# What are the intended use cases for CustomCollectionType vs. UserCollectionType in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, orm, persistence

What are the intended use cases for [CustomCollectionType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/CustomCollectionType.html) vs. [UserCollectionType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/UserCollectionType.html) ?

Which one should I use if I want to use my own collection with Hibernate?

[This example](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/m91832311.html) uses [UserCollectionType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/UserCollectionType.html). I could not find examples using [CustomCollectionType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/CustomCollectionType.html) though, how can [CustomCollectionType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/CustomCollectionType.html) be used ?

What are the advantages/disadvantages of using [CustomCollectionType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/CustomCollectionType.html) vs. [UserCollectionType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/UserCollectionType.html) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UserCollectionType` is for when you want to rely on Hibernate's collection handling when handling persistence, but want to expose a different class to clients of your persistent objects.  For example, if you have an Auction and a one-to-many of Bids, you might want Hibernate to treat this a set when persisting, but you might want getBids() to return a FastSet (as in your link).

`CustomCollectionType` is for when you want to persist a collection in a completely different way with different semantics using a new implementation of PersistentCollection.  I'm not sure when you'd really want to do this except to change some Hibernate framework behavior.